# How to separate regex values?

Tags: php, regex

the user makes a selection and I want to test if the selection is valid. So e.g.

```
 preg_match("/(test1/test2|test3)/", $value)
```

The problem is that one value is `test1/test2`, but each test is treated as a single value.  Any idea how to change that to have `test1/test2` as a single value?

Eg:

```
test1/test2,
test3
```

Comment: You should escape `/` in `test1/test2` ie. `preg_match("/(test1\/test2|test3)/", $value)`

Comment: That isn't very clear at all, and to my knowledge, not a valid PHP regex (unescaped slash). Can you should an example of input text, output and expected output (or valid/invalid)? `test1/test2` is captured as a single value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need a regex here? How about:

```
 $value = 'test1';
 $valid = in_array( $value, array( 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ), true );
```

That seems less intensive, but functional.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of an [in_array](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
$array = array('test1/test2' 'test3');

if (in_array($value, $array))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the specifics of php regex but i think if you wrap it in parenthesis to make it a group it might work.

Also if your not doing anything more fancy than your example it might just be faster/easier to look check if the value is in an array

Answer (score 0):

Best to use strpos or other string functions unless you're actually matching a pattern. But since you've asked....

```
preg_match("/(?:test1\/test2)|(?:test3)/", $value)
```